# Face-ID enabled without info.plist key?

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

So I have an application currently on the store that supports `Touch-ID` login,

- A user with an **iPhone X**  **iOS: 12.1.4** sent me a video that he can login using his **face ID** and as i recall i never implemented the **face ID** feature yet so i've downloaded the store version on an **iPhone X** with the same **iOS**  and i couldn't login with **Face ID**  but it did ask me for the mobile pass code which is the right.

Now rolling back to my store version code, there is no **info.plist** key  that indicates using **Face-ID** which is this one

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application wants to access your FaceID scanner</string>
```

And the code for checking biometrics is this,

```
let myContext = LAContext()
var authError: NSError? = nil
    if #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.12, *) {
        if !myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy(rawValue: Int(kLAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics))!, error: &authError) {

            switch authError?.code{

            case (LAError.touchIDNotEnrolled).rawValue?:
                User.sharedUser.touchIDState = .TouchIDNotEnrolled
                self.touchIDButton.isHidden = true
                break

            case LAError.passcodeNotSet.rawValue?:
                User.sharedUser.touchIDState = .TouchIDNotEnrolled
                self.touchIDButton.isHidden = true
                break


            default:
                User.sharedUser.touchIDState = .TouchIDNotSupported
                self.touchIDButton.isHidden = true
                break
            }
        }else{
            User.sharedUser.touchIDState = .TouchIDEnrolled
            // if(User.sharedUser.touchIDState == .TouchIDEnrolled){
            self.touchIDButton.isHidden = false
            // }
        }
    }
```

My **iPhone X**  is not showing the application that its using **Face-ID** and simply when in use directs me for the passcode thats the expected result  ... however the video is so clear from the user that he is logging in with **Face-ID** !! how is this even possible ?

Comment: yes its possible,

Comment: any explanations links @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: yes you are not split out the device LAContext type is touchID or face ID, actually LAContext working with touch & face ID also, so if its connected its   automatically returns the success message, based on the message we will handle the process

Comment: but the info.plist missing a key + why its not working on other devices as expected

Comment: your ? is sound good, but the existing user how long used your application.

Comment: your app won’t crash if you have Touch ID permissioning setup correctly and the user uses Face ID

Comment: the expected result is asking for passcode because we have not added the face id feature ... that what i  mean my other  device is working just fine ... the user device is working  with face id XD ....

Comment: the store version have no key in the info.plist for using the face id

Comment: ya I agree your point, are you submitted your query to apple team once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189179/discussion-between-mohmmad-s-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Is your app built using an older version of the iOS SDK (iOS 10 or earlier, I think)? If so, iOS will allow the user to authenticate using Face ID in any circumstance where you allow them to use Touch ID, even if you haven't added those keys to your `Info.plist`. The first time, they try this, they'll see a prompt warning them that the app wasn't designed for Face ID.

Comment: unfortunately the version the current build where this happens is +12, and was archived using xCode  10

Comment: Is it possible the user is running an older version of the app that was linked against iOS 10 or earlier, instead of your newest release? That might explain why they see different behaviour to you.

Comment: They show me the app version the latest they updated from store

Comment: Hmm, then I have no idea, sorry. I’ll think about it some more.